# html:21:40 - error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type

Tags: angular, tslint, angular10

HTML

```html
<star-rating
  value="{{(res.popularity| number : '1.0-0') /20 }}"
  totalstars="{{totalstar}}"
  checkedcolor="yellow"
  uncheckedcolor="black"
  size="24px"
  readonly="true"
  (rate)="onRate($event)"
></star-rating>
```

And I have many issues as shown in the picture. Could someone please explain the issue

[image]

Comment: The first line of [`Decimal`](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) pipe's doc: **Transforms a number into a string**. You're attempting to divide string by a number. Moreover, it's not a good idea to have calculations in interpolation. In default change detection strategy they will be triggered for each CD cycle and might lead to performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael D said above in the comment, the DecimalPipe (a.k.a | number) converts the number to a string, so you can't pass it further to an @Input() of type number.

What you can do to fix it in a clean and reusable way for your project, is to create a custom pipe that takes a string representing a decimal and convert it to the 'number' type. Here's how:

#### as-number.pipe.ts

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'asNumber',
    pure: false
})
export class AsNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): unknown {
        return parseFloat(value);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to declare it in the `app.module.ts` file (or the Feature module where you're gonna use it):

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AsNumberPipe } from './pipes/as-number.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

    AsNumberPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now you can use it in your html template like this:

```html
<star-rating
  value="{{(res.popularity | number : '1.0-0' | asNumber) / 20 }}"
  totalstars="{{totalstar}}"
  checkedcolor="yellow"
  uncheckedcolor="black"
  size="24px"
  readonly="true"
  (rate)="onRate($event)"
></star-rating>
```

---

### Bonus:

From what I see in your error dump, you also have some errors related to two other input bindings of the StarRating component.

1. `totalstars="{{totalstar}}"` // **Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.**

To fix this you can use the same pipe we've created above, like this:

```html
totalstars="{{totalstar | asNumber}}"
```

2. `readonly="true"` **// Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.**

For this you just need to make sure that you're passing indeed 'true' as a bool value, by wrapping the attribute with angle brackets:

`[readonly]="true"`

So in the end your html tag would look like this:

```html
<star-rating
  value="{{(res.popularity | number : '1.0-0' | asNumber) / 20 }}"
  totalstars="{{totalstar | asNumber}}"
  checkedcolor="yellow"
  uncheckedcolor="black"
  size="24px"
  [readonly]="true"
  (rate)="onRate($event)"
></star-rating>
```